# Display mail sender doesn't work javamail

Tags: java, outlook, office365, jakarta-mail

I try to send a mail from Java, and I want the sender's email address to be display when the user reads his mails.

This is my code :

```
    public void sendMail(String smtp, String sender, String pswd, String receiver, String subject, String mailContent) {
    final String username = sender;
    final String passwd = pswd;
    final String from = sender;
    Properties props;
    props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, pswd);
        }
    });
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test_text <no-reply@society.be>"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,receiver);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setContent(mailContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        msg.saveChanges();
        Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("Echec lors de l'envoi du mail : " + e);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Transmission du mail éffectuée avec succès !") ;
}
```

The problem is Outlook (Office365) doesn't show me what I want :

[image: The sender name that is really display]

What I want is to display the entire email address, or a customize name, but not just "no-reply".

Do you guys have an idea why this doesn't work ?

Comment: It works for me using an IMAP mail server.  What version of JavaMail?  What mail server are you using to read the message?  If you use Outlook to save the message as an eml file, does the From header in the file show what you expect?

Comment: I use smtp. My javamail version is 1.4.3 (javax.mail, mailapi). I tried to send it to gmail and office accounts. I read them both in gmail and outlook. But the sender's name is not display. If I save it as an txt file, I see the "from" value is "no-reply".. Can't see anything about "test_text". However, In the debug, I can see this : 

Infos:   From: test_text <no-reply@society.be>

Comment: You're using a **very** old version of JavaMail.  While I don't think it's related to your problem, please upgrade to [1.6.2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) or [1.6.3](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/).  If the debug output shows the right information being sent to your server, then the problem is with your server or your mail reader.  I can't imagine why the server would strip this information out, but if it's not in the .eml file or "view source", then that's what's happening.

Comment: I think you're right, there is no traces of my custom sender name in the "view source" page. However, I can see it in the logs (session.setDebug(true))... I'll come back to you as soon as I have an answer about this. Thanks again. (I upgraded to 1.6.3 and it didn't change anything).

Comment: Ok, so as no-reply is a user of our AD, changing his display name did the job. I didn't know that the display name in our AD would strips the custom sender name out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as no-reply is a user of our AD, changing his display name did the job. I didn't know that the display name in our AD would strips the custom sender name out.